# svn: automatically accept server certificate

Tags: ssl, subversion

I'd like to automize a build process which involves getting some code from an svn repository. The server certificate is not automatically trusted.

Things that I tried but that don't work:

1. `svn checkout --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username name --password password --no-auth-cache -r revision https://server.address/trunk/`

   results in

   `svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate has expired, issuer is not trusted`
2. `echo "t" | svn checkout --username name --password password --no-auth-cache -r revision https://server.address/trunk/`

   results in the same result

   `svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate has expired, issuer is not trusted`

However, when using

`svn checkout --username name --password password --no-auth-cache -r revision https://server.address/trunk/`

then the dialog `(R)eject or accept (t)emporarily?` appears, and when pressing 't' the source gets fetched.

Particularly the manual method and the `echo "t"` method confuses me, because it should actually be the same thing. Has anybody an explanation for this or knows a solution that could work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expect`, is a command line application to simulate user interaction, just install it and copy the following script to a new executable file.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 20
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]

spawn svn checkout --username $user --password $password --no-auth-cache -r revision https://server.address/trunk/

expect "(R)eject or accept (t)emporarily?" { send "t\r" }

interact
```

Just edit the script to your needs, basically it will run the command and read the output, then will "type" t and return(\r) and release the session

The timeout is for how long `expect` will wait for the output before giving up, the user and password are variables that will be set from command line arguments, so you must call the script as `expectscript.exp user password` or you can just remove those 2 lines and put the user and password directly on the spawn line.

---

EDIT:

Other possible solution:

This might take care of `svn` "cleaning" STDIN before reading the answer by constantly sending the answer from a forked process to the terminal.

```
# The following command will fork to the background
# and keep sending 't^M' (^M is return) for 5 seconds to the terminal
{ for X in {1..5}; do printf %b 't\r' >$(tty); sleep 1; done } &

svn checkout --username name --password password --no-auth-cache -r revision https://server.address/trunk/
```

I hope it works, I have no way of trying it.

EDIT2:

On second thought this may work on an interactive session, but provably not on a script.

EDIT3:

Maybe delaying the answer in a pipe?

```
(echo -n; sleep 5; printf %b 't\r') | svn checkout --username name --password password --no-auth-cache -r revision https://server.address/trunk/
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer. Though it actually doesn't solve my problem (requires extra software package), it works and thus earns the reputation. If somebody gets it working without `expect`, I'm happy about the answer.

Comment: @user236012: try the solution in my edit, I do not have a `svn` server with a bad cert to try.

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo "t"` input is ignored most probably because `svn` flushes the stream before asking the user for input, so the string provided by `echo` gets discarded. This behavior is quite widespread for important questions where an unwanted input could ruin something or lead to actions which are impossible to undo. You could use `strace` to confirm that.

The solution using `expect` by Dalvenjia will likely work (though technically a race condition will still be there), or you can try to wait past the flushing the quick & dirty way:

```
{sleep 3; echo "t"; } | svn checkout ...
```

Comment: thank your for the answer. I could't get it working this way..

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad you got it working. I guess we'll never know what the problem was without debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The `--trust-server-cert` option doesn't accept expired certificates, AFAIK. I believe it only works for unknown certificate authorities. Your SVN version might affect this behavior as well, as indicated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544633/how-to-trust-an-expired-ssl-certificate-with-subversion).

I'm not really sure why the `echo` command isn't working since I can't replicate the behavior. The 't' may be echoed to a different prompt or point where input is possible. Instead you might try the `yes` command:

```
yes 't'
```

As part of your command:

```
yes 't' | svn checkout --username name --password password --no-auth-cache -r revision https://server.address/trunk/
```

Comment: doesn't work either, same error message..

Comment: @user236012 and similar approaches like `<<< t` also don't work? It's odd that your SVN client doesn't seem to be using stdin. Is there anything strange about the environment?

Answer (score 0):

When using `--trust-server-cert` with the `--non-interactive` option enabled, use it this way:

```
svn checkout --username $user --password $passwd -r $Revision --no-auth-cache --trust-server-cert --non-interactive https://server/trunk/ local_checkout_path
```

This will surely workout.

Here is some sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$0
passwd=$1
svn checkout --username $user --password $passwd -r $Revision --no-auth-cache --trust-server-cert --non-interactive https://server/trunk/ local_checkout_path
```

Comment: expect part can be ignore this way. try this out (Y)